# Datepicker pickadate prefill multiple picker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, pickadate

I have multiple datepickers to choose a range and send it with the form. For this is use following library [Date picker](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/). Now i want to prefill the datepicker with given values.

My html:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="select-date-from" name="date-from" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="select-date-until" name="date-until" autocomplete="off">
```

JS:

```
$('.meetings-datepicker').pickadate({options});
```

I already found:

```
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate()

// Use the picker object directly.
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
```

It works if I replace the class with an id but then i would have to initialize each datepicker seperate. So how can you fill out multiple pickers if they are initialized through a class?

I already tried sth like this:

```
var picker = $input[0].pickadate('picker');
picker.set('select', new Date('{{ request('date-from') }}'));
```

but it throws an error:

> TypeError: $input[0].pickadate is not a function

I also tried

```
$('#select-date-from').pickadate('set', 'select', (new Date('{{ request('date-from') }}')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These have to be initialized individually by each field

```
$('#select-date-from').pickadate({options});

$('#select-date-until').pickadate({options});
```

Comment: Please See this first: [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @ankitsuthar, good grief, its a good answer..